# Is there way to determine if apps has just finished installing the first time?

Tags: android, installation

My app download 5 files .apk from internet and after each file of 5 install successful first time, I want to send device id to the server.

so is there way to check apps installed success the first time

Comment: Please explain in detail, what exactly you want. I cannot understand what is the problem

Answer (score 5):

You can get first installation time using

```
Date app_install_date = null;
long installation_date = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime;
app_install_date = new Date(installation_date);
```

I think you can compare that to current time and do what you require.

Comment: You can't check whether app is installed first time like this.

Comment: This will tell you when your application was installed for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

you can track your app usage and other statistics through Google Analytics.You can also send any data like device id through Google Analytics to Google Analytics Site.